# Публикация exe файлов ClickOnce c#

Tags: c#

Возникла проблема с ClickOnce, а именно:

Публикую проект
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Всё бы ничего, но у меня есть там chromedriver, и он не публикуется и не загружается на компьютер пользователя. То есть, сразу после

```
new ChromeDriver();
```

у меня выходит ошибка, потому что неоткуда запускать. Пытался найти как сделать так, чтобы программа и все компоненты устанавливались на компьютер пользователя, а не просто подгружались с моего сайта, но не смог разобраться. Мог бы просто скопировать все нужные файлы из папки Release, но у меня стоит автообновление программы в случае, если появилась новая публикация..
Что мне сделать, чтобы сохранить автообновление от ClickOnce и чтобы заставить chromedriver работать? Есть ли такое решение в VS 2017?

З.Ы. Предпочтительно это сделать всё так же, одним файлом.

З.Ы.Ы. Получилось сделать изначально установив в определённую папку chromedriver, а в коде прописать:

```
new ChromeDriver("путь");
```

Но это не лучшее решение

Comment: А при сборке у вас эти файлы копируются?

Comment: @tym32167 в папках Debug и Release они присутствуют. А вот в файлах приложения публикации их нет http://prntscr.com/p3br1g

Comment: Они туда сами копируются или вы их руками копируете?

Comment: @tym32167 я их добавил с помощью NuGet. Они автоматически потом добавляются в обе папки

Comment: @tym32167 единственное, я вручную менял версию файла chromedriver.exe. Но он уже устанавливался из пакета NuGet. Только другой сборки был

Comment: @tym32167 http://prntscr.com/p3bw92 весь список файлов в папке Release

Comment: У вас на скрине есть кнопочка "файлы приложения", убедитесь что все необходимые файлы там присутствуют и имеют нужный параметр публикации.

Comment: @rdorn в том-то и дело, что их нет.. И добавить нельзя :с